# Easier way to create time inhomogeneous Markov Chain

Tags: r, survival-analysis, markov-chains

I have a series of observations of a machine that can be in different states. I
want to create a multi state model where the survivability of each state is modelled
with a Weibull distribution. My real data set has 119 states and about 30K
observations. I do not want to create the transition matrix that is required
for mstate manually so found a way to derive it from the data.

Two questions:

1. Does anyone know whether there is a better way to set up the
   transition matrix or is an easier way to achieve my goal than the code below?
2. What is the purpose of the `shape()` function in the `flexsurvreg` command?

## Data

```
require(mstate)
require(data.table)
test_data <- data.table(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                        state = c("A", "B", "End", "A", "A", "End", "B", "End"),
                        time = c(10, 30, 100, 10, 30, 102, 5, 50))
```

## Derive the Transition matrix

(any advise how to shorten this code?)

```
require(markovchain)
mc_fit <- markovchainFit(test_data[, state])

states <- apply(mc_fit$estimate@transitionMatrix, 1, function(x) {
  list(which(x > 0))
})


# Unpack by one layer.
states <- lapply(states, function(x) {
  return(x[[1]])
})

# Store names temporarily.
states_names <- names(states)
require(stringr)
# Make all END states absorbing.
states <- lapply(names(states), function(x){
  if (str_detect(x, "End")) {
    return(c())
  } else {
    return(states[[x]])
  }
})
# Assing the names back to make reading easier.
names(states) <- states_names
tmat <- transMat(states, names = mc_fit$estimate@states)

tmat_dt <- as.data.table(tmat)
tmat_dt[, event := rownames(tmat)]
trans_mapping <- melt(tmat_dt, id.var = "event")
trans_mapping[, trans_key := paste(event, variable)][, c("event", "variable")
                                                     := NULL]
setnames(trans_mapping, "value", "trans")

test_data[, c("next_event",
              "tstop") := 
              list(Hmisc::Lag(state, shift = -1),
                   Hmisc::Lag(time, shift = -1)),
by = id]

test_data <- test_data[state != "End"]

test_data[, trans_key := paste(state, next_event)]

test_data <- merge(test_data, trans_mapping, by = "trans_key")

test_data[, trans_key := NULL]
setorder(test_data, id, time)

test_data[, event := TRUE][next_event == "End", event := FALSE]
```

## Create the time inhomogenous Markov chain

```
require(flexsurv)

# Build a clock forward time inhomogeneous Markov chain.
cfweib <- flexsurvreg(Surv(time, tstop, event) ~ trans
                      + shape(trans), data = test_data,
                      dist = "weibull")
tgrid <- seq(0, 100, by = 0.1)
mfwei <- msfit.flexsurvreg(cfweib, t = tgrid, trans = tmat)
```

Comment: Verging on code review..?

Comment: Sorry, I just added all my code because I didn't want to get a comment that I failed to add code.

Comment: Was this code was copied from some external source? This looks wrong: `states <- lapply(names(states), function(x){
  if (str_detect(x, "End")) {
    return(c())
  } else {
    return(states[[x]])
  }
})`. You should explain in more detail. Make little sense to replace a dataframe (or matrix) with something derived only from it's names.

Comment: I add that since I want all end states to be absorbing. This is essential I believe because `markovchainFit` does take `id` into consideration.

Comment: The next operation on `states` turns the third element of `states` into `NULL`. Is that desired behavior? Have you examined `states` after each stage of its transformation to see what you were getting?

Comment: I did and no operation turns `states` into `NULL` or I am missing something crucial. The code works. It just seems a cumbersome way of creating the transition matrix that is required for `mstate`.